# If a random variable X can take values -1 and 1, is the variance of X 1?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, machine-learning, variance

Consider a particle that starts at position 0. At each time step, the particle moves one step to the left or one step to the right with equal probability. What is the variance of the particle at time step n?

$X = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n$

The answer is n but I'm a little confused about how to calculate $Var[X_i]$.

As far as I understand it X can take values -1 and 1. Thus,
$$
E[X_i] = \mu = 0
$$

which implies

$$
Var[X_i] = E[X_i^2].
$$

Now, the solution says that $Var(X_i) = 1$. Is that because $Var(X_i) = E[1^2] = E[(-1)^2] = 1$ or is there something I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: You are missing nothing, except that the title of he question is confusing.

Comment: @KurtG. how so?

Comment: Title says "expected value of $X$ is $1$" while in the body it is zero and you are concerned with variance not expected value.

Comment: Oh yes, that's a mistake. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

$X_i^2=1$ so $Var(X_i)=\mathbb E[X_i^2]=\mathbb E[1]=1$.

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: I never understood the difference between answer and comment. Is it written somewhere which should be which?

Comment: Something to read is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/949989). If you participate in the review queue you will learn from seeing many low quality posts what a good answer should be. In short: low quality questions should not attract answers. Your answer is just a repetition of what OP already wrote. Confirming that in a comment would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $\mathbb P(X_1=1)=p = 1-q = \mathbb P(X_1=-1)$, by independence we have
$$
\mathbb E[S_n] = \mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n (-q+p) = n(2p-1).
$$
Moreover, the variance of $X_1$ is
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X_1) = \mathbb E[X_1^2] - \mathbb E[X_1]^2 = (q(-1)^2+p)-(2p-1)^2 = 4pq.
$$
Again by independence we have
$$
\operatorname{Var}(S_n) = \operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n 4pq = 4npq.
$$
In the symmetric case where $p=q$, the variance at time step $n$ is simply $4n(1/2)^2 = n$.